# Handling an exception and continuing a loop

Tags: python-3.x, exception, python-decorators

I am writing an ETL framework in Python 3.7 that uses functions as "tasks" bearing a special decorator. Most of these tasks run a loop. If something raises an exception in the loop, I want the function to handle this exception by recording data about the failure, and continuing on with the loop.

This is a simplified example of what I have so far:

```
class TaskExecutionError(RuntimeError):
    def __init__(self, msg="", context={}):
        self.msg = msg
        self.context = context

    def __str__(self):
        return self.msg or "Error executing task."


def task(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_ts = datetime.utcnow()
        try:
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)

        except TaskExecutionError as e:
            logger.exception(f"Task execution error will be logged: {e}.")
            fail_data = {
                    "task_name": fn.__name__,
                    "args": list(args),
                    "kwargs": kwargs,
                    "context": e.context,
                    "fail_message": str(e),
                    "fail_time": str(datetime.utcnow()),
                    # etc.
                }
            )
            # Write failure data in an object store

        finally:
            end_ts = datetime.utcnow()
            logger.info(f"*** Wallclock: {end_ts - start_ts}.")

    _wrapper.is_task = True
    return _wrapper


@task
def test_fail_log(a, b, c, kwa=1, kwb=2):
    """
    Test handling failures.
    """
    for i in range(10):
        if i % 3:
            raise TaskExecutionError(context={"i": i})
        else:
            print("All's well")
```

This works well as far as I see the message being printed and saved, however of course the execution breaks as soon as the first exception is raised.

How shall I tackle this so that execution continues?

It seems like I can't use the very convenient exception mechanism and I probably have to devise a custom `handle_failure()` function or so. But I am uncertain about the best way to pass the function decorator's context to the `handle failure()` function while I call it from within the decorated function.

Since I am going to use this mechanism in several `@task` decorated functions, I'd like to have a lightweight call if possible, without a lot of arguments.

Thanks for any suggestions you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using `inspect`, which I don't like to use too often, but seemed necessary here:

```
def task(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_ts = datetime.utcnow()
        try:
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)

        finally:
            end_ts = datetime.utcnow()
            logger.info(f"*** Wallclock: {end_ts - start_ts}.")

    _wrapper.is_task = True


def handle_task_failure(exc, local_ctx={}):
    caller_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    wrapper_frame = caller_frame.f_back
    caller_ctx = wrapper_frame.f_locals
    print(f"Context: {caller_ctx}")
    logger.exception(f"Task execution error will be logged: {exc}.")
    fail_data = {
            "start_time": caller_ctx.get("start_ts"),
            "runid": caller_ctx.get("runid"),
            "task_name": caller_ctx.get("fn").__name__,
            "args": list(caller_ctx.get("args")),
            "kwargs": caller_ctx.get("kwargs"),
            "context": local_ctx,
            "fail_message": str(exc),
            "fail_time": str(datetime.utcnow()),
            "traceback": format_stack(caller_frame),
    }
    # Save failure data in object store

@task
def test_fail_log(a, b, c, kwa=1, kwb=2):
    """
    Test handling failures.
    """
    for i in range(10):
        try:
            if i % 3:
                raise RuntimeError("All's borked.")
            else:
                print("All's well.")
        except Exception as exc:
            handle_task_failure(exc, {"i": i})
```

On the other hand, I don't need a custom exception class and the call to handle the failure, which is repeated in several fun is very light-weight.